# Add multiple instances of SVG node to DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a list of SVG files, so I load them all with SnapSVG.
Now I want to randomically add multiple instances of each SVG to a container, in a way that some of them get repeated.

The problem is that when I add one that's been already added, the first one disappears.

```
    var objects; // pretend this is a list of objects which are SVG files loaded with SnapSVG.

    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_OBJECTS; i++) {
        let r = getRandomInteger(0, svgs.length - 1);

        container.appendChild( objects[r].node );
    }
```

Here, it grabs the node from the object and appends it to container:

```
container.appendChild( objects[r].node );
```

I'm assuming the object still holds a reference to the node (because it can be added again on future iterations).

But if we grab the node again and add it to the DOM, the node that was added previously disappears which makes me think it's the same one and only instance of the node.

Does that make sense? If so, is there a way to clone the SVG objects or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DOM node (be it HTML or SVG) can't be at several places (any node points to its parent).

You must clone the node using [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).